# Leaflet Draw and Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay freeze browser

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I created a leaflet layer by using the "[Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay](https://github.com/teralytics/Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay)" plugin and geojson data.
Later I added a "[Leaflet Draw](http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.draw/docs/leaflet-draw-latest.html)" plugin for drawing polyline, all work correctly but when I zoomIn or zoomOut the browser freeze without any error.

Someone has encountered the same problem?

Comment: Have you tried in other browsers? Have you got a demo that others can test?

Comment: Works good for me. Try this [example](https://kboul.github.io/leaflet-d3svgoverlay-with-leaflet-draw/) and let me know how it behaves.

Comment: @kboul this example freeze my chrome Versione 69.0.3497.100 (Build ufficiale) (a 64 bit)... I drawed a polyline then zoom in and the browser freeze

Comment: You are right! The issue is reproducible when drawing a polyline and zoom in to the max level. I have tested with a marker and the issue is not reproducible in that case. Perhaps there is an incompatibility between these two libraries and probably Leaflet.D3SvgOverlay introduces this bug to Leaflet Draw

Comment: Sad story... you know another library to plot geojson with d3 on leaflet? tnks

Comment: I don't know any other to share with you but I m sure can find something if you make a good research

Comment: have you filed a bug report?

Comment: yep, on D3svgovelay and leaflet draw boards

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Leaflet Draw and I fixed it by removing the feature group from the map ahead of zooming and adding it back right after:

```
// example setup
let map = L.map('leaflet');
let featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
let drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
  edit: {
    featureGroup: featureGroup,
  },
});

// fix
map.addEventListener('zoomstart', (event) => {
  featureGroup.removeFrom(map);
});
map.addEventListener('zoomend', (event) => {
  featureGroup.addTo(map);
});
```